# C++ Проблема с std::cin std::cout

Tags: c++, ввод, поток-ввода, cin, std

у меня есть проблема, код спокойно комплиируется в exe, а также первые два входа работают идеально, но когда приходит время для третей переменной программа начинает работать не так, при этом в коде всё одинкаово
https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler - тут вы можете быстро скомплиировать.

```
#include <iostream>



int main()
{
   std::cout << "Enter a: "; // просим пользователя ввести любое число
   int a = 0;
   std::cin >> a; // получаем пользовательское число и сохраняем его в переменную a


    std::cout << "Enter b: "; // просим пользователя ввести любое число
   char b = 0;
   std::cin >> b; // получаем пользовательское число и сохраняем его в переменную b


   std::cout << "Enter c: "; // просим пользователя ввести любое число
   int c = 0;
   std::cin >> c; // получаем пользовательское число и сохраняем его в переменную a
   std::cout << "Finish" << std::endl; 
   return 0;

}
```

https://prnt.sc/rlb818

[image: скриншот]

Первые две переменных идут правильно вот что происходит на третей

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать чтобы я мог вводит третью переменную у меня это c. Если есть какие-либо вопросы задавайте.

[23.03.2020 19:22]
Поправил: Изменил названия переменных, для большей простоты и понимания.

Comment: Так же рекомендую использовать. using namespace std;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну а что вы хотите?

```
char dll = 0;
std::cin >> dll;
```

Раз в `char` читаете - читает один символ (вас не удивляет вывод `D` на картинке?). А все остальное - `LL.dll` - идет из буфера при чтении

```
std::cin >> lvls;
```

Понятно, что это не число - вот реально в `lvls` ничего и не читается, для `cin` выставляется флаг ошибки `fail` (вы его не проверяете...).

Все просто.

Читайте строки - в строки :)

Comment: Я только начал изучать с++, помогите понять что именно не так?  И как исправить на правильный код? Я попытался прочить и увидеть ошибку, но так её и не заметил :(

Comment: Ещё кое-что, там картинка не правильная сейчас заменю.